# Create an indicator variable for a table relationship after an outer join

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am working with data from a data cube, meaning I cannot easily control the structures of my underlying data. My underlying data looks like the below. As a Cube datasource, each one of these columns also is its own table with define join relationships between one another. For example, to select the Group1 column on its own would look like 'Group1'[Group1].

| Group 1 | Group2 | Group3 | Desired Column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | x | 1 |
| 2 | a | y | 1 |
| 3 | a | y | 1 |
| 4 | b | y | 1 |
| 5 | b | y | 1 |
| 6 | c | z | 0 |

I am trying to create a variable that reflects what is shown in "Desired Column" so that I can include results for any value of Group2 that matches to the "y" value of Group3.

I am not very fluent with DAX, but my preliminary thoughts on an approach are to run a FILTER on Group3 for "y", select values of Group2, and then somehow use those Group2 values in a CONTAINS statement in a further FILTER. Here is my current, non-functional attempt:

```
Is_Y = CONTAINS(NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN('Group2','Group3'), 'Group3'[Group3], "Y")
```